# Findbugs non-transient non-serializable instance field in a utility class

Tags: java, findbugs

Findbugs returns a warning for the class below:

Class ServiceUtils$1 defines non-transient non-serializable instance field val$request

Bug type SE_BAD_FIELD (click for details)
In class ServiceUtils$1
Field ServiceUtils$1.val$request
In ServiceUtils.java

I cannot understand what is wrong with this code...

```
public class ServiceUtils {

  public static String getFileName(final PostFileRequest request) {
    String separator = "-";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
        .append(request.getFirstName())
        .append(separator)
        .append(request.getLastName())
        .append(separator)
        .append(request.getAddress())
        .append(separator)
        .append(request.getNumber());
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that's your full code or even the code that produces the error.

Comment: Well, believe it or not, it is... Which is the reason for my question. Now maybe findbugs is pointing in the wrong direction?

Comment: Recompile your code and rerun findbugs. This is otherwise unreproducible and should be closed.

Comment: Can you provide the PostFileRequest class code?

Comment: Please just delete your question. This serves no useful purpose.

Comment: Please delete! This is polluting the beautiful thing that is stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, FindBugs was running against old code. Guess I forgot to clean the project.